# Why is $(( sum += i )) in bash telling me "command not found"?

Tags: bash, scripting

The goal is to have a bash script that sums up the integers from 1 to N, with N being defined by the user. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter an integer greater than zero: " N  #allows the user to enter a value, which is then read from stdin and assigned to N

sum=0

for ((i=0; i<=N; i++))

do

  $((sum+=i))  #add i to sum each iteration

done

echo "The sum of the numbers from 1 to $N is $sum"
```

The output:

```
Enter an integer greater than zero: 5
-bash: 0: command not found
-bash: 1: command not found
-bash: 3: command not found
-bash: 6: command not found
-bash: 10: command not found
-bash: 15: command not found
The sum of the numbers from 1 to 5 is 15
```

The summation is correct. I realize that the summation for each iteration is causing an error of some sort (b/c 0, 1, 3, 6...  is the value of the summation for each i), but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. Is there a way to debug in vi? Thanks

Comment: `$((...))`, like `$(...)`, substitutes the result of the operation into the contents of a new command to run. Thus, if the result of `$((sum+=i))` is 3, it tries to run `3` as a command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so sum=$((sum + i)) does not implement command substitution like   $((sum+=i))   ?

Comment: Hmm. When I said "the current syntax", I think I was referring to heemayl's answer. Sorry -- the comment should have been there rather than on the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop the `$` in front:

```
((sum+=i))
```

`$(())` will do arithmetic expansion, and the result of the expansion would be treated as a command to run leading to the error messages.

Comment: The only obvious space for future extension is to notate the current suggestion as a bashism and add a POSIX-compliant alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid the problem by using a colon as the first character of the line:

```
:  $((sum+=i))  #add i to sum each iteration
```

or remove the `$`

```
((sum+=i))  #add i to sum each iteration
```

The problem with the `$(( ))` is that it has an output, which (without the : )
is being interpreted as a command to be executed (1, 3, 6 ... etc).

You may reduce the code to this shorter version:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter an integer greater than zero: " N  

for (( i=0,sum=0 ; i<N ; i++,sum+=i )); do : ; done

echo "The sum of the numbers from 1 to $N is $sum"
```

or to this (a lot) faster:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter an integer greater than zero: " N  
echo "The sum of the numbers from 1 to $N is $(( N*(N+1)/2 ))"
```

Comment: Your "short" version is only marginally shorter, but much less clear.